# Bouganville, new green parts but no flowers

Tags: flowers, bougainvillea

Here is my bouganville,

[image: Potted Bouganvillea with no flowers]

I bought it two months ago. I removed all dry flowers, so none remain. It does not seems to suffer since it is producing new trees, but:
No flowers, and new born parts are lighter green.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Too frequent watering, or too frequent pruning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your description and the photo (lush foliage) you do supply too much fertilizer and water.

> For bougainvilleas it is best to think of them having the same
> watering requirements as Mediterranean plants such as lavender and
> delay watering until the soil is somewhat dry to a winters depths.
>
> This emulates their natural preferred flowering conditions (they
> flower during the dry season in their native South America) and the
> water stress triggers the develop of the colourful flowers (and
> bracts).

From [this](https://www.gardenerreport.com/bougainvillea-isnt-blooming/#:%7E:text=The%20reason%20for%20bougainvillea%20not%20flowering%20is%20because,much%20fertilizer%20causes%20lush%20foliage%20with%20fewer%20flowers.) source.

In case you are in a climate zone similar to USDA Hardiness Zone 9 or cooler, also make sure to place your [Bougainvillea](https://www.rhs.org.uk/plants/45443/i-bougainvillea-i-purple-robe/details) on the hottest and most sunny spot in your garden.

Comment: You should be more careful on your statements: you do not known where the OP is living, so "the hottest and most sunny spot" may not be correct.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Agree. OP is from Italy, but such statement should be limited. Edited.