# How to get flowers on my Bougainvillea

Tags: flowers, bougainvillea

After answer provided here:
https://gardening.stackexchange.com/a/62869/39970

I gave less water and no more fertilizer.  I managed to have some flowers, but just on a small part of the plant:
[image]

I tried to turn the plant to have more sun on other sides, but to no effect, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Most likely you are not doing anything wrong. Your bougainvillea looks healthy and has started to produce flowers. It is my experience that it will quickly become covered with flowers after a few initial ones. Take a look in the corner of the leaves, and you will probably find flower buds in development. If you wonder why only one part of your plant has flowers, then consider whether you always are watering the opposite part.